# How to convert array to json decode format

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to convert my array to JSON format how can I do that.
    Below is my code

```
    $arr['more_images'][] = $datas;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr['more_images']);
    echo '</pre>';
In above code i am getting output like this
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://sale4allz.com/sale4allz/public/uploads/product_more_images/178_3749.jpg
            [1] => http://sale4allz.com/sale4allz/public/uploads/product_more_images/178_4923.jpg
            [2] => http://sale4allz.com/sale4allz/public/uploads/product_more_images/178_9362.jpg
        )

)
</pre>
But I want output like this

        [
          {
               http://sale4allz.com/sale4allz/public/uploads/product_more_images/178_3749.jpg
    }
          {    http://sale4allz.com/sale4allz/public/uploads/product_more_images/178_4923.jpg
    }
          {    http://sale4allz.com/sale4allz/public/uploads/product_more_images/178_9362.jpg
            }
    ]
```

How can I do this? If anybody knows solution than please tell

Comment: use `echo json_encode($arr['more_images']);`

Comment: You are not going to get those curly braces on indexed elements.  And if you `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` then everything gets converted to objects and you will lose the square braces.  Your question is Unclear.  And please explain WHY you wish to change the structure -- what is the benefit?

Comment: It is a client requirement that I want each element in a { } separate. The square bracket is not required

Answer (score 1):

You should use below logic:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $arr['more_images']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$arr['more_images'][] = json_encode($datas);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr['more_images']);
    echo '</pre>';
```

**OR**

```
$arr['more_images'][] = $datas;
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r(json_encode($arr['more_images']));
        echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I am getting output like [
    [
        "http://sale4allz.com/sale4allz/public/uploads/product_more_images/178_3749.jpg",
        "http://sale4allz.com/sale4allz/public/uploads/product_more_images/178_4923.jpg",
        "http://sale4allz.com/sale4allz/public/uploads/product_more_images/178_9362.jpg"
    ]
]